# Simple Beamer Template for Total Beginners

Tags: beamer, equations

Is there a template that allows me to create slides with only some simple formulas at most?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your LaTeX distribution has includes Beamer, here is a simple plain beamer presentation of a slide with an "equation".

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \(a=b\)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Each slide is a `\begin{frame} - \end{frame}` Frame titles are added by `\framettitle{}` within each frame. You can also create a title slide using the `\author{}` and `\title{}` in combination with `\titlepage` in a frame.

EDIT: a useful link provided by @textenthusiast:

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/beamer-presentation

Comment: Hi Peter Jansson,if you feel it's worth while you can include this link which has a good collection. http://www.latextemplates.com/template/beamer-presentation

Comment: @texenthusiast Thanks for pointing out the link. I will add it but you could also add it as a comment directly to the question if you like.

Comment: @PeterJansson Perhaps `$a=b$`?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Thanks, I was not originally thinking in terms of a minimal example in every sense of the word but why not :-). I decided to go with the LaTeX shorthand instead of TeX dito even if it is sligtly less "minimal".

Answer (score 3):

You'll find quite a few samples installed as part of your distribution.

Have a look in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/
```

or if you want to view it online, http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/