# Latex presentation

Tags: presentations

I try with following code, but have many errors... Am I need to install special things for create presentation? It has any special steps for starting and executing? I tried a lot. But, I could't run a simple code so far....

```
\documentclass[ Options]{prosper}
\title{ aa}
\subtitle{ ss}
\author{ ccc} 
\institution{ssf }
\slideCaption{sfsf }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{slide} [transition] { title }
Material for the slide
\end{slide}

\overlays{n}{
\begin{slide} [transition] {  title }
Material for the slide
\end{slide}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run it with these 'fillers' in (such as `Options`), or did you use real values here?

Comment: The `prosper` class is old and has largely been replaced by the `powerdot` class.  However, both of these classes require compilation with `latex+dvips` (as opposed to `pdflatex`) since they make extensive use of Postscript commands.  If you've never used a LaTeX presentation class before, I would recommend `beamer` over `powerdot`.  Most people here prefer it.  See [Which package to use for presentations ? Beamer, Prosper, or Other](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16204) for some discussion.

Comment: @JosephWright I used above same code .used 'Options' word .Is it wrong?

Comment: @AlanMunn I tryed with 'beamer'.But have errors.I execute it ,first Latex ,then DVI-PS,finally DVI View.Is it wrong?errors are,            Undefined control sequence,
Missing \begin{document},Environment slide undefined.,\begin{document} ended by \end{slide},

Comment: I used 'frame' for replcing 'slide'.It like to be ok...Is it correct for ppt presentation?

Comment: The `beamer` manual has a wonderful tutorial.  See also [Simple Beamer Template for Total Beginners](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102791).

Comment: @Emalka: `beamer`was made for `pdflatex`, so just run `pdflatex` on the file. If you have to use `pstricks` in your slides, have a look at `powerdot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above `prosper` is pretty outdated. Have a look at the following `beamer`example.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\author{Jane Doe}
\title{My first presentation}
\subtitle{foobar}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\frame{
\maketitle
}


\frame{
\frametitle{Hello World}

\begin{itemize}
\item abcde
\item fghij
\item klmno
\end{itemize}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1234
\item 5678
\item 9012
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: beamer]